# How to improve Forge Viewer performance in local environment

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load a local model, and I am using the following load option:

```
option = {
  "env": "Local",
  "document": "0/0.svf",
  "useADP": false,
  "useConsolidation": true,
  "consolidationMemoryLimit": 104857600,
  "createWireframe": true,
  "bvhOptions": {
    "frags_per_leaf_node": 512,
    "max_polys_per_node": 100000
  },
  "isAEC": true,
  "disablePrecomputedNodeBoxes": true
}
```

```
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv, optionObject);

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
   viewer.start(options.document, options);
```

Viewing the model in local environment is significantly slower (lower FPS, less responsive) when compared to "AutodeskProduction" environment using the same setup. Is there any additional settings that can further improve the performance? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Viewer is yours? Make sure you are on v6.6 if not. Are you using the same load options for `AutodeskProduction` and getting better performance? Try turn on `Smooth Navigation` in the settings and see if that helps - if the issue persists send the model thru (via a sharing service like weTransfer/Dropbox) to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @BryanHuang I am using v6.6. I am using `ForgeViewer.js` in the Forge Viewer tutorial ( [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/) and [link](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/forge.learning/blob/master/docs/viewer/2legged/ui.md)) to load the model for `AutodeskProduction` . I found out that there seem to be some "default" load options because the looks of the viewer are different if I load `Local` without any settings. It looks to me that those "default" options can be found via `NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().loadOptions`

Comment: The load option listed in question is the result I get in `NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().loadOptions` [(image for AutodeskProduction)](https://imgur.com/a/t1AgQJC), without `bubbleNode` and `sharedPropetyDbPath` since they are different by model. After using these options for local environment I can see that the viewer has become more responsive and is becoming more alike compared to the `AutodeskProduction` . Do you have any insight on whether the two option will affect the performance, and if not, is there any other "default" settings which makes the two environment behave differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say among these options a fined-tuned combination of `useConsolidation` and `consolidationMemoryLimit` probably did the trick for you - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-consolidated-geometry) for details:

```
const initializerOptions = {
   useConsolidation: true,
   consolidationMemoryLimit: 150 * 1024 * 1024 
}
```

However the balancing act here is when you have large numbers of BVH (as can be noticed in the BVHoptions) that might neutralize the performance gain so you'd want to play up to those factors.